# Suppress repeating values

Tags: oracle, mysql-5.5

I have a table that has columns like following. Batch number is a database design thing like row number

```
demand_id        batch_number    debit status     customer
     34               1             yes
     34               2                             jack 
     35               1             no                
     35               2                             kate
```

OUTPUT:

```
demand_id        batch_number    debit status     customer
     34               1             yes
                      2                             jack 
     35               1             no                
                      2                             kate
```

Comment: Which one is it? Oracle or MySQL? This can easily be done in Oracle but not in MySQL

Comment: To clarify: Is your objective to "not show one value in one *cell* if the *same* value appears on *top of it*? (i.e.: it appears in the same column, but the previous row)?  Do you want this for all columns, or just some?

Comment: i think you do it with row partition then call it as a derived table. That whenever rank is not 1, then demand id would be null.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I have tried and tested it and it gives the output you wanted (this was tested in Oracle):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN dr <> 1 THEN NULL
        ELSE demand_ind
    END demand_ind,
    batch_number,
    debit_status,
    customer
FROM (
SELECT
    demand_ind,
    batch_number,
    debit_status,
    customer,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY demand_ind ORDER BY rowid) AS dr
FROM test2
) test3;
```

Comment: Why `ORDER BY rowid` abd not `ORDER BY batch_number`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `case when batch_number = 2 then null else demand_id end as demand_id` in the select clause.